# How to pickle individual steps in sklearn's Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, pipeline

I am using `Pipeline` from sklearn to classify text.

In this example `Pipeline`, I have a `TfidfVectorizer` and some custom features wrapped with `FeatureUnion` and a classifier as the `Pipeline` steps, I then fit the training data and do the prediction:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

X = ['I am a sentence', 'an example']
Y = [1, 2]
X_dev = ['another sentence']

# classifier
LinearSVC1 = LinearSVC(tol=1e-4,  C = 0.10000000000000001)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
       ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), max_features= 4000)), 
       ('custom_features', CustomFeatures())])),
    ('clf', LinearSVC1),
    ])

pipeline.fit(X, Y)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_dev)

# etc.
```

Here I need to pickle the `TfidfVectorizer` step and leave the `custom_features` unpickled, since I still do experiments with them. The idea is to make the pipeline faster by pickling the tfidf step.

I know I can pickle the whole `Pipeline` with `joblib.dump`, but how do I pickle individual steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pickle the TfidfVectorizer, you could use:

```
joblib.dump(pipeline.steps[0][1].transformer_list[0][1], dump_path)
```

or:

```
joblib.dump(pipeline.get_params()['features__tfidf'], dump_path)
```

To load the dumped object, you can use:

```
pipeline.steps[0][1].transformer_list[0][1] = joblib.load(dump_path)
```

Unfortunately you can't use `set_params`, the inverse of `get_params`, to insert the estimator by name. You will be able to if the changes in [PR#1769: enable setting pipeline components as parameters](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/1769) are ever merged!

Comment: How do I load it in from within the Pipeline?

Comment: It is almost unbelievable that such a useful feature does not exist.